# Allow only one accordion item to be open at a time

Tags: reactjs

I created an accordion component, but currently, you can expand all the accordion items with clicks. I want to make it so if you have one open and click a new one, the previous one closes. Below is my code:

```
export default function useOpenController(initialState) {
  const [isOpen, setOpenState] = useState(initialState)

  const toggle = useCallback(() => {
    setOpenState((state) => !state)
  }, [setOpenState])

  return { isOpen, toggle }
}

export const Accordion = ({ section, key }) => {
  const { isOpen, toggle } = useOpenController(false)

  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col items-start justify-start'>
      <ExpendableColumn
        question={section.question}
        isOpen={isOpen}
        toggle={toggle}
      />
      {isOpen && <TextSection text={section.answer} />}
      <div className='acc-underline'></div>
    </div>
  )
}

export const ExpendableColumn = ({ question, toggle }) => {
  return (
    <div className='column-container' onClick={toggle}>
      <p className='text-3xl'>{question}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export const TextSection = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <div className='text-container mt-4'>
      {text}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I only see one `ExpendableColumn`. Can you show the scenario where you render multiple of them?